# Form submission progress monitoring (non-ajax and without XHR)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to monitor the submission progress of a form using JQuery without switching to post the form using either AJAX or XmlHttpRequest (I already know how to track upload using these two methods).

To be particular, assuming the following form:

```
<form action="Add" method="post">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="email" name="username" />
    ...
    <label>Profile Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="profileimage" />
    <Button>Submit</Button>
</form>
```

and the following pseudocode

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on(When Form Submited, function(){
         Start Monitoring upload progress;
         Display upload progress feedback;
    })
})
```

And by considering this pseudocode, it is clear that I want it to work in an unobtrusive way. Would it be possible to do anything like this? (Again no AJAX, or XHR)

Comment: When you hit "submit", your browser page will be terminated and will be redirected to another page (form action attribute) so you can't do much as far as I know

Comment: @Justinas: That's right, but when uploading a file the progress is shown by certain browsers at the bottom, I mean is there any way to do a similar thing?